# How to fit image in td html css / dompdf

Tags: jquery, html, css, dompdf

Basically, I create a pdf using dompdf. But, dompdf is listening common css and html. So, I have a table in html. There is a `<td>` which is contains a lot of image.

Is it possible to manipulate this `<td>` know if image does not fit , so image will be continous below previous image.

This is my code.

```
**CSS**
table, td, th {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
       width: 100%;
        }

.table-no-border tr td th{
      border : none;
 }

 td {
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
  }

**HTML**
<tbody>
    <?php
       $no = 1;
          foreach ($image->result() as $row) {
               $file_thumb = explode(", ", $row->FILE_THUMB);
               echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td style='vertical-align: text-top ; text-align: left;'>$no</td>";
                 echo "<td style='vertical-align: text-top ; text-align: left;'>$row->SPEC <br> $row->CONTRACT_NO <br> $row->SIZE <br> $row->COIL_NO</td>";

                // a lot of image in td //
                 echo "<td>";
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_thumb); $i++) {
                        echo "<img src= '$file_thumb[$i]' >";
                    }

                echo "</td>";

                echo "<td style='vertical-align: text-top ; text-align: left;'>$row->CHECK_LIST</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            $no++;
          }
   ?>
 </tbody>
```

This is looked now [image: Description]

Any help it so appreciated

Answer (score 2):

dompdf, while fairly capable with tables, does have some rendering quirks. Many times you'll never run into any of these quirks, but it looks like you've found one.

It appears dompdf is having trouble reflowing content as it builds the table. More specifically the images are throwing it off. What might help is to wrap the images in a container and specify a width on the container. This would give dompdf a definitive constraint to work with related to the width of the image column. The only down side is that you would have to know in advance a good width for that column.

```
// a lot of image in td //
echo "<td><div style='width: 200px;'";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_thumb); $i++) {
  echo "<img src= '$file_thumb[$i]' >";
}
echo "</div></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table td img {
    display: inline-block;  
    float: left;
}
```

I also suggest removing your inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

How about add to table style

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed; //new line
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be more of a design problem than anything.

Placing each image in it's own td and / or on it's own row possibly would fix your issue.

If you want a more reactive design, I would suggest abandoning tables altogether and using floating divs.

You could use javascript to determine the width of images, etc, and then adjust your table style accordingly, but I'm not sure how dompdf responds to javascript.

Comment: dompdf does not support JS at all. For that you would need to use something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). However, if the page is first previewed in the browser you *could* send the JS-modified page back to the server for rendering.

Comment: He is talking about a PDF rendering Engine, so reactive design is not an answer at all.