# Is it possible to put Images in table's **td** tag in mpdf Laravel library

Tags: laravel, mpdf

I am trying to add an 100 X 100 pixel image in a table in mpdf. But the table disappears when I do so.

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><img src="https://someimage.jpg" width=100 height=100></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

But when I use  tag outside table it fetches the image and shows it perfectly fine.

How do I put image in table in mpdf (is there any trick)?

Comment: Instead of `width=100 height=100` you can try `style="width : 100px !important; height : 100px !important;"`

Comment: I applied your suggestion, but still getting the same result.

Comment: dompdf allows to handle tables with images as I have tried it eariler, any plans to use dompdf

Comment: I asked my project manager to use dompdf, but he wouldn't listen.. Actually a lot of work has already been done with mpdf, hence can't change the library.

Comment: @bhucho does dompdf handle images inside table well?

Comment: @sta if dompdf handle images inside table. We can think about using it.

Comment: @AbhinavKeshri you can use dompdf, if you have no plan to use any other language without english https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324087/dompdf-problem-with-displaying-nepali-character/63418338#63418338

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917784/how-to-fit-image-in-td-html-css-dompdf, though you should know the exact width to be taken by pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to put images in a table in mpdf. Earlier i was making syntax mistake. I had forgot a comma. Sorry for inconvineance.

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><img src="https://someimage.jpg" style="height:50px; width:100px;"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience when I tried to use MPDF with tables and images inside cells I couldn't manage to set the correct image sizes. I fixed it with div's instead of table. If possible try this solution